# Are pins of WOG bridge package numbered?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, schematics, rectifier, packages

The WOG package used for a diode bridge looks like this:

[image]

As I'm preparing a PCB layout footprint for this device, I need to assign pin numbers. Those pin numbers map to the schematic and ensure the pins are connected to the right circuit nodes in the PCB layout.

In studying [the datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88501/b40c1500g.pdf) and doing a general web search on "wog package", I can't find mention of the pin numbering for the package.

Am I missing something?

If not and it's up to me to decide, I'd be inclined to make the top pin (+) pin 1, and then number counter-clockwise as viewed from the top. My rationale is that when viewing the component from the top, the printing is aligned such that the package flat is at a 45 degree angle and the (+) pin is at the top. Does that seem consistent with convention?

This would produce the following mapping:

- 1: \$+\$
- 2: ~ (A)
- 3: \$-\$
- 4: ~ (B)

Comment: Note my edited answer. You've actually got the wrong numbering for what you said you wanted.

Comment: Assign whatever numbers you want is my philosophy. BTW I'm amused by the abbreviation. 20 years ago people would think you a rasist!!

Comment: Ooh, I see what you're saying now after a quick Googling. That *is* an unfortunate package naming. I'm sure the Vishay folks meant no offense :)

Comment: Pretty much all bridge recitfiers are marked like this from the larger [PBL 40x](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/70/35482_DS.pdf) to the small [DI10x](http://pribor-systems.ru/fromoremax/PDF/Panjit/DI100S_SERIES.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The pins aren't numbered in this case, they're labeled.**

If you want to assign numbers, the orientation and ordering you've chosen is consistent with some other pin numbering formats. It's worth noting that the diagram in the datasheet is the ***bottom*** view. They helpfully did not annotate that fact, but you can see it by looking at the 3D version and the diagram together:

[image][image]

If you wanted top view numbering, starting with upper left and counting counter-clockwise (to be consistent with most DIP packages) the numbering is actually:

1: ~ (A)
2: −
3: ~ (B)
4: +

Otherwise, if you only use this package for this rectifier and nothing else, just use the labels and not arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Yes, I did notice they did that! Took me a second pass to work it out, I actually ended up just using the physical package I happen to have handy. Given it's not defined, I suppose my question comes down to what is the most conventional choice for pin 1. When the text on the top is aligned for reading, the pins are in a diamond shape, with the (+) pin at the top of the diamond. So I was figuring that for pin 1; especially since the second choice would be the "left" AC pin, which is ambiguous when only the label is known.

Comment: @scanny Good to catch that. It's a very common mistake for new EEs. At least this package is symmetrical, you could just rotate it after blowing up a few in testing, often that's not the case. Overall you'll find that there are at least as many standards as companies making datasheets. Pin 1 for upper left is usually a good bet though.